# Conditionally extracting multiple substrings using grepl specifically, indexing extractions to return cumulative value

Tags: r

Good day to Everyone,

I am having trouble with completing this challenging task, whereby I would like to find an elegant approach to:

1. I need to use an adaptable method like a loop for each row element in  'Zone'
2. to extract multiple substrings row-wise from 'country_name' grouped by 'Zone' elements
3. store the row-wise multiple substrings as an indexed value to use against df2
4. match the indexed values against the dataframe in df2
5. Calculate the total population and mutate it against df1

Essentially the challenge is, the method should NOT be fixed against any particular element in the dataframe.

The first dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(zone, country_name)
zone = c("M", "N", "O")
country_name = c("The USA, Canada & Mexico are part of North America", "Canada like Australia is a Commonwealth member", "The UK is still finalizing its exit plans from the EU")
```

The second dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(zonal_region, country, population)
zonal_region = c("M", "M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O")
country = c("USA", "Canada", "Mexico", "Canada", "Australia", "UK", "Australia", "UK", "Canada")
population = c(323.4 , 36.29, 127.5, 36.29, 24.13, 65.64, 24.13, 65.64, 36.29)
```

This is how my final output looks like:

```
df3 <- data.frame(zone, country_name, total_population)
zone = c("M", "N", "O")
country_name = c("The USA, Canada & Mexico are part of North America", "Canada like Australia is a Commonwealth member", "The UK is still finalizing its exit plans from the EU")
total_population = c(487.19, 60.42, 65.64)
```

I have been having trouble extracting the multiple substrings and indexing their values against df2 given their zone.

It would be very much appreciated if anyone can solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  fuzzy_left_join((df2 %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)),
                  by = c("zone" = "zonal_region", "country_name" = "country"), 
                  match_fun = str_detect) %>%
  group_by(zone, country_name) %>%
  summarise(total_population = sum(population)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

**Output is:**

```
  zone                                          country_name total_population
1    M    The USA, Canada & Mexico are part of North America           487.19
2    N        Canada like Australia is a Commonwealth member            60.42
3    O The UK is still finalizing its exit plans from the EU            65.64
```

**Sample data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(zone = structure(1:3, .Label = c("M", "N", "O"
), class = "factor"), country_name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Canada like Australia is a Commonwealth member", 
"The UK is still finalizing its exit plans from the EU", "The USA, Canada & Mexico are part of North America"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(zonal_region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("M", "N", "O"), class = "factor"), 
    country = structure(c(5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Australia", 
    "Canada", "Mexico", "UK", "USA"), class = "factor"), population = c(323.4, 
    36.29, 127.5, 36.29, 24.13, 65.64, 24.13, 65.64, 36.29)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: I used the method from this solution against my current working problem and the method works great with fuzzy join versus using the str_extract_all from stringr; this allows the method to be highly adjustable and fits additional changes I had to make

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by doing a `left/right` joins with the two datasets after extracting the 'country' from the 'country_name' column of 'df1', and doing a `group_by` `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
un1 <- unique(df2$country)
df1 %>%
   mutate(cntry =  str_extract_all(country_name, paste(un1, collapse="|"))) %>% 
   right_join(df2, by = c('zone' = 'zonal_region')) %>% 
   group_by(zone) %>% 
   summarize(total_population= sum(population[country %in% cntry[[1]]])) %>% 
   left_join(df1) %>%
   select(zone, country_name, total_population)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  zone  country_name                                          total_population
  <fct> <fct>                                                            <dbl>
#1 M     The USA, Canada & Mexico are part of North America               487. 
#2 N     Canada like Australia is a Commonwealth member                    60.4
#3 O     The UK is still finalizing its exit plans from the EU             65.6
```

Comment: I used this method and it also works great for the above stated problem, but from some reason stringr seems a little less adapatable versus the capability of fuzzyjoin. However, the above solution also is correct and works, but I prefer the solution with the fuzzyjoin due to the extended adaptability!